# My footer isn't appearing at the bottom of the page but in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, sass

My footer isn't appearing at the end of the page. It's appearing in the middle.
I have tried all other answers given by others on a similar question, but it didn't work as well.

Here is my html: -

```
<body>
    <div class="nav-container">
    </div>

    <div class="hero-area">
    </div>


    <div class="main-container">

        <section id="about">
        </section>

        <section id="services">
        </section>

        <section id="portfolio">
        </section>

        <section id="contact">
        </section>

    </div>


    <ul class="social-items">
        <li>FACEBOOK</li>
        <LI>INSTAGRAM</LI>
        <LI>YOUTUBE</LI>
    </ul>

    <footer>
        <h1>This is footer!</h1>
    </footer>

</body>
```

My footer is appearing anywhere inside the portfolio area.
Here is my sass: -

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: $light-mode;
  background: $dark-mode;
  @include dark-white-transition;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  background: $dark-mode;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  color: $light-mode;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try `position: fixed;` instead of `absolute` for your footer

Comment: Not working. It just fixes footer to the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding width and height properties to the html tag could do the trick.

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #f00;
  background: #0f0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  background: #00f;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #0ff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="nav-container">
    </div>

    <div class="hero-area">
    </div>


    <div class="main-container">

        <section id="about">
        </section>

        <section id="services">
        </section>

        <section id="portfolio">
        </section>

        <section id="contact">
        </section>

    </div>


    <ul class="social-items">
        <li>FACEBOOK</li>
        <LI>INSTAGRAM</LI>
        <LI>YOUTUBE</LI>
    </ul>

    <footer>
        <h1>This is footer!</h1>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: If I do this, two scroll bars are being created!

Comment: Yes. You're right. It's due to the margin fusion of the UL tag with the body. I edited my answer to solve this problem. Is it ok for you now ?

Comment: Still not working. Here is my full code https://github.com/ajaybirbal/day-night

Comment: In your CSS, you can remove the "height:200vh", and add a "padding-bottom:220px" in .main-container.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Raphael! I forgot that I added this for testing purposes!